# Tag popups on post body

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, popup

When we point a cursor to a tag it gives a popup containing a brief description about what that *keyword* means. But when tags are added to a post body, it doesn't appear.

Instead a tooltip appears saying ***show questions tagged 'xxxx'***,

[image]

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52612105/2408342)

---

but the popup comes in the preview when editing the post.

[image]

---

It is better if the `tag-popup` appears when the mouse pointer is on a tag in a post body.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue it's not better, because if you unwittingly put your cursor on that tag, or it gets bumped onto that tag, or somehow ends up there while you read the post... Suddenly the text you're reading is obscured, which not only is annoying, but can also cause you to lose your place as you move the mouse. (Sites that do this with random text, linking to searches and displaying about it on hover, are the bane of my internet existence.)

Not only that, but if someone uses tag markup for a non-tag, for example here on Meta proposing a new tag, then users will be confused when no pop-up is shown for that tag. It will be inconsistent.